# Java upgrading from 1.8 to JDk 17.0.8 version for NetBeans 15 Ant project -factory already defined at java.base/java.net.URL

Tags: ant, upgrade, java-17, netbeans-15

**Introduction**

I've come across an unexpected error caused by calling Java

> Version Found..17.0.8 java.lang.Error: factory already defined at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1228)

in an Netbeans Ant application that is being updated to Netbeans 15 and jdk 17 from netbeans 8.1 and jdk 1.8 version.

**System information**

```
Operating System        = Windows Server 2019 version 10.0 running on amd64
Java; VM; Vendor        = 17.0.8; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.8+9-LTS-211; Oracle Corporation
Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 17.0.8+9-LTS-211
Java Home               = C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17
System Locale; Encoding = en_US (asgraphicruleside); Cp1252
Boot & Ext. Classpath   =
Application Classpath   = C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\lib\\boot.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\lib\\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\lib\\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\lib\\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\lib\\org-openide-util.jar
Startup Classpath       = C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\asm-9.3.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\asm-commons-9.3.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\asm-tree-9.3.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\core-base.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\core.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar;C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-15\\netbeans\\platform\\core\\org-openide-filesystems.jar;D:\\JAVA_17\\build\\cluster\\core\\locale\\core_asgraphicruleside.jar
```

**Warning**

run.run:

```
Aug 22, 2023 10:57:02 PM org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory register
SEVERE: No way to find original stream handler for jar protocol
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.net.URLStreamHandler java.net.URL.handler accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @27973e9b
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:59)
at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.\<clinit\>(JarClassLoader.java:117)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:153)
at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:60)
at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Java Version Found..17.0.8
java.lang.Error: factory already defined
at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1228)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.installURLStreamHandlerFactory(Framework.java:1765)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.\<init\>(Framework.java:232)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:63)
at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:146)
at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:115)
at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1445)
at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1254)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:316)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:252)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:298)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:173)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:142)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:299)
at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

WARNING \[org.netbeans.core.modules\]: Use of OpenIDE-Module-Class: Loader in com.adminserver.asgraphicrulesidemodule is obsolete.
```

I tried below options as per forms : updated class paths with arguments " --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED"

Updated spring and Jakarta and maven version as per compatibility of jdk 17. updated NetBeans modules as per NetBeans 15 supports.

Comment: The common recommendation is first upgrade to Java 11, fix all problems and then make next step to 17.

Comment: @Robert - We have upgraded to java 11 version too. we didn't found this issue. when we tried to upgrade to jdk17 we are getting this issue.

Comment: Seems to me like an incompatibility of Netbeans (respectively the used Eclipse OSGi environment) with java 17, I would open an issue here: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues.

Comment: Since the error is within **java.net**, perhaps try adding the option `--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED`? That said, if everything worked when you upgraded from 8 to 11, I don't understand why a subsequent upgrade from 11 to 17 would provoke this problem unless it is a NetBeans 15 issue. Regardless, consider using a newer version of NetBeans than 15 if that is feasible, since if it is a NetBeans 15 issue it may have been fixed in later releases.